# Internal data having array of objects could not be rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

component is getting data in the format given as below

**demo.json**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "john",
  "addr": [
    {
      "addr1": "xyz",
      "addr2": "abc",
      "addr3": "st"
    },
    {
      "addr1": "xyz",
      "addr2": "abc",
      "addr3": "st"
    }
  ]
}
```

when I try to render the data, I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
render() {
  console.log(this.state.itemDetail.addr); // able to see log as [{...},{...}]

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> detail</h1>
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.itemDetail.name}</p> // able to display this
        <div>
        // getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
            {this.state.itemDetail.addr.map(item => {
              return <p>{item.addr1}</p>;
            })}
          </div>
          // error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
          <p>this.state.itemDetail.addr[0].addr1</P>; 

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when data is available inside render(), why internal data array of objects have issue? how to display this?

**EDIT:**
Providing below, ItemDetail code. after impl modifications suggested, execution doesn't throw errors but doesn't display addr or addr1.
data is fetched from local json-server using local demo.json.

**ItemDetail.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ItemDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ItemDetail: {}
    };
  }
  fetchItemDetail() {
    fetch(` http://localhost:4000/items/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          ItemDetail: res
        });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchItemDetail();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Item detail</h1>
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.ItemDetail.name}</p>
          <p>{this.state.ItemDetail.destination}</p>
          {Array.isArray(this.state.ItemDetail) &&
            this.state.ItemDetail.addr.map(item => {
              return <p>{item.description}</p>;
            })}
          <p>
            {Array.isArray(this.state.itemDetail) &&
              this.state.ItemDetail.addr.length &&
              this.state.ItemDetail.addr[0].description}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.state.itemDetail.addr` coming from? -> Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Added extra information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Put in a check for `this.state.itemDetail` to be not equal to undefined and then run the map. It's possible that it's undefined for first render and not for subsequent. I think the following should solve the problem.

```
{this.state.itemDetail && this.state.itemDetail.addr.length!==0 && this.state.itemDetail.addr.map(item => {
          return <p>{item.addr1}</p>;
        })}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example to help support your explanation?

Comment: Hey I have provided one in the original answer. I hope that suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that you'll always get the right data, one of the most important things in programming is validating you data before you use it. Check if the value exists before using it. use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if the value is array.

```
render() {
 console.log(this.state.itemDetail.addr); // able to see log as [{...},{...}]

return (
  <div>
    <h1> detail</h1>
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.itemDetail.name}</p> // able to display this
      <div>
        // getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
        {Array.isArray(this.state.itemDetail.addr) && this.state.itemDetail.addr.map(item => {
          return <p>{item.addr1}</p>;
        })}
        </div>
        // error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        <p>{Array.isArray(this.state.itemDetail.addr) && this.state.itemDetail.addr.length && this.state.itemDetail.addr[0].addr1}</P>; 

     </div>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why is _"add a check"_ the answer on _"how can I get the content of `this.state.itemDetail.addr`"_? o.O

Comment: and the code you posted, won't work as it fails here ```{Array.isArray(this.state.ItemDetail)```, I believe ```this.state.ItemDetail``` is an object not array. change it to ```{Array.isArray(this.state.ItemDetail.addr)```

Comment: @Andreas sorry I thought you were the op, because op tries to access a value that doesn't exist.